# How can I test Paypal Express Checkout integration with Malaysian Ringgit (MYR) currency?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

We're developing a service for customers in Malaysia and would like to use Paypal Express Checkout for payment processing

According to the paypal documentation:

> **Malaysian Ringgit**
>
> Note:This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only

When trying to run test payments in Sandbox mode, the checkout process errors out:

**"This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."**

I'm able to proceed using USD or SGD as the currency - so I believe the problem is only when I'm using MYR.

Paypal advertises Express Checkout on it's [Malaysian site](https://www.paypal.com/my/webapps/mpp/express-checkout), so I'm sure it's available to malaysian customers - the question is how can I test that it's working?

Any insight would be appreciated.